# Get path without file name save dialog

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I would like to extract the selected path from Save dialog, excluding the file name.

The following code retrieves the full path + the file name with its extension.

```
placeToSaveDocument = Path.GetFullPath(saveFileDialog.FileName);
```

Please do not suggest to use Folder Browser Dialog instead, because I have a reason why not to use it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Forgive me for asking: what is the reason for not using the Folder Browser Dialog? I may be that the reason is relevant for the answers you get on your question.

Comment: Are you really looking for a FolderBrowserDialog? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

Comment: @FredrikMörk, Further usage of file name, or give user the option to set his desired file name in addition to the desired saving place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking for `Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileDialog.FileName)`.

Example:

```
string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext";
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
//directoryPath = "C:\MyDir\MySubDir"
```

Comment: Which value you meant in "yourPath"? saveFileDialog.FileName?